# Delphi Dataset.Prior vs Dataset.Next Performance

Tags: delphi

In Delphi, is there a performance penalty for using Dataset.Prior as opposed to Dataset.Next?

Background:

I have a routine that searches for a specific record in a dataset. I start with the last record in the dataset and work my way backwards using Dataset.Prior until I find a match. I use this back-to-front approach simply because (in practice) the record I'm looking for is much more likely to be near the end of the dataset, so in my mind starting at the back will find the record more quickly.

This logic is however based on the assumption that Dataset.Prior and Dataset.Next have more or less the same performance overhead. Is that the case?

Comment: that how ISAM tables may work like DBF, CSV and Paradox.
But ISAM is very rarely used now, when there are a lt of free light SQL engines, even in your cellular phone.

And that is not how SQL tables work. If you want top target Firebird, SQLite, NexusDB and any other flexible information storage, you need to read some tutorial about SQL, why it was invented, what are its design goals and how you should use it.

Comment: what have your tests proven?  You should simply time your function using both methods.

Comment: Why aren't you just using SQL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends very much on the dataset and the database that is behind it. Some don't even support it (so called 'unidirectional datasets').

The problem you described sounds like it needs a more specialized query, rather than your current solution. If you can specify more details in your query, you will receive less data in your dataset, and possible even just the record you need. In almost any case, filtering is faster when done by the database.

If you need to do the searching/filtering in code, then maybe you can ask your database to at least sort the data in a way that puts the more likely records (probably by date) in front.

But if you still need to know for your specific dataset if there is a difference, you can just loop through your entire dataset front to back and back to front and measure the difference. 
To do this, make sure you open the query/dataset first, then use DataSet.Last to jump to the last record, because some datasets don't fetch all data at once, but this will force them to. After that, you can loop to the first record, and then again loop to the last record, while measuring each loop with a high precision counter (QueryPerformanceCounter).

Comment: even if an underlying cursor is unidirectional the dataset can still implement `Prev` method provided it does not move the current record out of the internal dataset's record cache.

Comment: +1, I have deleted my answer since I realized that it does in fact depends on how the descendant DataSet was **implemented**. I have never noticed performance issues with the `TWhatEverDataSets` I worked with in the past (as long as the cursor was `clUseClient` and bi-directional) - But that does not mean I can generalize that for *all* DataSet descendants.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of rows in the dataset is not too large, then I'd use a DataSetProvider to pump it into a ClientDataSet, then do sorting, filtering, searching, etc in that ClientDataSet.

Since you tend to walk most of the records anyway, the one-time cost at the beginning for fetching the records will likely payed back with reduced search times.

If this sowkr for you and you have an appropriate license, you can even go the DataSnap way and skip the DAL-secific dataset altogether and pump everything into the ClientDataSet.

Comment: This does not address the question asked at all.

Comment: I posted it because I think it answers an underlying question. Maybe my reading inbetween the lines was wrong. Hopefully the OP will let us know.